# Implementing AJAX posts filter using Twig in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, twig

I'm trying to implement an AJAX filter in WordPress according by category. This filter perfectly works if I use a PHP/HTML theme but right now I'm trying to make it work in a theme using Twig/PHP.

This is the WP function inside **functions.php**:

```
function ajax_filter_function() {
  if( isset( $_POST['categoryFilter'] ) )
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['categoryFilter']
      )
    );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
      echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  else :
    echo 'No posts found';
  endif;

  die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myFilter', 'ajax_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myFilter', 'ajax_filter_function');
```

This is the form in a separate file called **post-filter.twig**:

```
<form id="filter" action="{{ site.url }}/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST">
  <select name="categoryFilter">
      <option value="">Select...</option>
    {% for term in terms %}
      <option value="{{ term.term_id }}">{{ term.name }} ({{ term.count }})</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <button>Apply filter</button>

  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="{{ fn('myFilter') }}">
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

This is the **JS**:

```
$('#filter').submit(function() {
    var filter = $('#filter');
    $.ajax({
        data: filter.serialize(),
        type: filter.attr('method'),
        action: filter.attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
          filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
        },
        success: function(data) {
          filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
          $('#response').html(data); // insert data
        },
      });
    return false;
  });
```

With the current setting what happens is that when I select the category and hit **Apply Filter** the AJAX filter loads the whole page inside the div with **id="response"**.

Any idea why? What am I missing?? Thanks :)

---

PS. This is the original PHP form:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <?php
        if( $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'orderby' => 'name' ) ) ) : 
 
            echo '<select name="categoryFilter"><option value="">Select category...</option>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
            endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
        endif;
    ?>
    <button>Apply filter</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myFilter">
</form>
<div id="response"></div>
```

Comment: Not sure if this would help locate the problem, but would it be possible to include in your question post the `data` value (if it doesn't have confidential information) that you are getting back in the `success: function(data) {...}` part of your code? In other words, I'm curious about what `console.log(data);` might show if you were to put that in the `success: function(data) {...}` part of your code and were to check the developer tools in your web browser console the next time you try running this code.

Comment: @summea ...thanks for your reply...what I get is the whole HTML page including `head`, `body` and `footer`...that's the bizarre thing...the filter doesn't render the single posts but rather the whole blog page

Comment: I'm curious: would it be possible to include your PHP/HTML example code of what the form looked like when it worked? I don't know if it's related, or if there's even an issue with this part, but I'm wondering if there's an issue related to the `value="{{ fn('myFilter') }}"` part in the twig version. I'm wondering if your `ajax_filter_function()` is really getting called in this twig version.

Comment: @summea ...I have edited the question...you can find the original PHP/HTML form at the bottom...cheers

Comment: Thanks for posting that! I've got to get going for now, but if you have a chance, does changing your Twig code's `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="{{ fn('myFilter') }}">` line to your previous HTML line `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myFilter">` in the related form do anything different? Looking at some of the [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/) and [WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags), I don't quite see which area the `fn()` part is from offhand. (Maybe it's from somewhere else?)

Comment: @summea ...now that I have changed the value to `value="myFilter"` I get the `No posts found` response from the function in functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. All I had to do is replacing the `'field' => 'id'` with `'field' => 'slug'` inside the `WP_Query` argument.

```
$args['tax_query'] = [
  [
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $_POST['categoryFilter'],
  ]
];
```

Comment: Glad it is working! How did you find out that the `slug` field needed to be used instead of the `id` field?

Comment: @summea ...I remembered that I had a similar issue in the past with a PHP/HTML theme...for some reason with `'field' => 'id'` the query wasn't working...when I changed it to `'field' => 'slug'` it worked...I don't have an explanation though...

Comment: No problem about that, mostly was curious if there was any reference links to add to your findings :) Nice to know it's something that can be fixed.